# Ajax request error by vue-resource

Tags: vue-resource

I am using vue webpack template to develop application using vue js 2, I am using vue resource for ajax

```
this.$http.get('http://localhost:8081/test/station.json')
          .then(response => {
              console.log(response);

          }, response => {
              // error callback
          });
```

but getting error "Failed to load http://localhost:8081/test/station.json: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access."

How to solve this

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your url with the json file doesn't have any headers so the call is not allowed. So you have to set the header to `content-type : application/json`

Side note:
You should not use vue-resource because it is no longer supported by the vue team. You should use something like [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-axios) for making Ajax requests

Answer (score 0):

Now I am using axios get request with header but getting same error, my code is below here

```
this.axios.get('https://feeds.citibikenyc.com/stations/stations.json',{
          headers: {
              'content-type': 'application/json'
          }
      }).then((response) => {
          console.log(response);
      }).then((error) => {
          console.log(error);
      });
```

Error is

Failed to load https://feeds.citibikenyc.com/stations/stations.json: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access